# Find set of limit points of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

> For $n\in\Bbb N,$ we define $$ A_n= \left \{ \left (x,\frac{x}n  \right ) \in \Bbb R^2 :x\gt 0 \right \}$$
>
> Let $A=\bigcup\limits_{n\in \Bbb N}A_n$. Find the set of limit points of $A$.

My idea for solution is: $B=A\cup\{(0,0) \}\cup\{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x\gt0 \}$

I want to prove that $A_n^{'}=A_n\cup{(0,0)}$ and I want to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n=\{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \gt 0 \}$. Can somebody help me solve this, I think I have good idea but I can't capitalize on it.

Comment: You should have $\left(\frac{x}{n},{x}\right)$ not the other way around

Comment: No, it is like i wrote it

Comment: Why I am getting -1 points

Comment: If you really mean that $A_n$ are all just $\emptyset$ so there's nothing much to talk about

Comment: Task 2. b) https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/nastava/difraf/dif/2014-15/kolokvij1.pdf

Comment: Can somebody else comment and see who is right?

Comment: @user160738 $\bigl(x,\frac{x}{n}\bigr)$ doesn't denote an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ here, it denotes a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: You're right in saying what $A_n'$ is, and you're right that $B = A'$ (well, you never say that, so I might misinterpret, but I believe that you list $B$ because you think it's the set of limit points of $A$). In your $$\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = \{ (x,0) : x > 0\},$$ what sort of limit of sets have you in mind? It's correct in a certain sense, but incorrect in others.

Comment: That's why I asked for help. I don't know how to write it. I've never worked with limit of sets. Can you help me prove that $B=A'$